# form submit inside navigation menu

Tags: php, javascript, html, form-submit

what i need is this

[image: My menu]

my php code is:

```
class logout{
    public function __construct(){
        session_unset();
        session_destroy();
        session_write_close();
        setcookie(session_name(),'',0,'/');
        session_regenerate_id(true);
    }


}
if(!empty($_POST['logout'])){
    $object=new logout();
}
```

for this i'm using the html code:

```
<ul id="navlist">
      <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="dates.php">Dates</a></li>
      <li><a href="candidate.php">Candidates</a></li>
      <li><a href="database.php">Database</a></li>
      <li><a href="password.php">Change Password</a></li>
      <li><a href='logout.php'>Log Out</a></li>
</ul>
```

for logout i need to do javascript form submit from an anchor which i've read is not secure.

if i do like this:

```
<li><a href=''><form method="post"><input type='submit' value='Log Out' name='logout' style="border:0px;" /></form></a></li>
```

i'm getting something like this:

[image: Bad Menu]

how to solve the problem (do i've to use javascript any how to submit the form?)

Answer (score 4):

You can do it via ajax if you have jQuery loaded. This way you can keep your nav styling as well.

```
<li><a href="#" class="log-out">Log Out</a></li>

$('.log-out').click(function() {
   $.post('logout.php');
});
```

Learn more about ajaxs shorthand for [$.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) or [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: i don't intend to create a logout.php. if i create, it solves my problem. i want to just include that much code inside header include and do the rest work via a logout command(though by javascript or jquery or form).

Comment: Well, you would still be posting to a controller method/api so you would have to create a logout script or action in the controller. Having a form inside your nav structure like that I would consider an odd design.

Comment: that class code is inside a class library i'm including in every page.
so if i create a logout.php, it'll only contain
`$object=new logout();` which i'm thinking not worthy for a whole new file.

Comment: You're still doing a POST to ['logout'] though, if that's publicly available via a shared service or controller method, you can still do a success:function() on the $.post and handle whatever you want (redirect, messaging,etc). I havn't worked with PHP classes enough to figure this out via a shared class. Sorry.

Comment: Np! Hope you can find a solution.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need to post this, simplify it ... change this line to use `$_GET`

```
if(!empty($_GET['logout'])){
    $object=new logout();
}
```

and to use `?logout=true`

```
<ul id="navlist">
      <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="dates.php">Dates</a></li>
      <li><a href="candidate.php">Candidates</a></li>
      <li><a href="database.php">Database</a></li>
      <li><a href="password.php">Change Password</a></li>
      <li><a href='?logout=true'>Log Out</a></li>
</ul>
```

now you can include your logout code on any page.

Comment: URL tweaking of get for a form, i don't think it's secure.

Comment: your logging some one out ?!? what needs to be secure about that

Comment: after trying everything, no doubt i didn't get what i wanted, but doing the process using ur method only. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to manually submit the form, here's a pure JS way to do this:

```
<li>
  <a href="" onclick="javascript: findForm('logout').submit()">
   <form id="logout" action="logout.php" method="post">
    <input type='submit' value='Log Out' name='logout' style="border:0px;" />
   </form>
  </a>
</li>

function findForm(id) {
  for (var i = document.forms.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (document.forms[i].id == id) return document.forms[i];
  }

  return null;
}
```

Comment: i'd like to use jquery instead. and this is my code
`$(function() {
 $("#logout").click(function(){
     $("#logout_form").submit();
  });
});`
but it seems to be not working. in a page two document.ready functions won't work?